# Replace steel post with aluminum

Tags: steel

I have a steel post that is 4" x 4" x .250" wall.  it is exposed in the Florida keys and want to replace with aluminum.  It sits on a concrete floor and supports a concrete floor above.  I have no idea on the load.  Make dimension is 8" x 8" as that is the width of the concrete beam above.

i have not found a "calculator" to run this for me.  thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Will need a structural engineer.  Guessing since I don't have a cement floor above my head, at least two or three times the size including wall thickness, maybe even more.  Those steel posts looking better now I guess.

Comment: i think you may be correct!  dealing with hurricane winds and 185 mph codes!  thanks

Comment: Not meaning to be morbid, but the Surfside condominium collapse shows what can happen when columns (and posts) supporting heavy loads aren't properly designed, or maintained.

Comment: "No idea of the load" usually means it is more than enough to flatten you.  Mistakes are not recommended.

Comment: In a sea coast environment , aluminum offers no significant corrosion advantage over steel.

Comment: Is your worry rust and failure or aesthetics? Could work on weather proofing instead, even exposed as it is you could prevent it rusting away with anual maintenance

Answer (score 3):

This question cannot be answered as asked.  So let me answer with what you need to do:

1. Consult a local engineer (i.e. one with a P.E. after his/her name) and who is qualified in the area of structural analysis you are interested it.  The engineer can calculate the load and then give you a design of a properly sized support structure.  If you want it to be Aluminum, be sure to point that out.
2. Hire a suitable contractor to do the actual work for you since specialized equipment and techniques are almost certainly going to be required.

This is absolutely not a DIY sort-of project and the stakes for you and anyone else using your property are quite high.

Answer (score 0):

Alumimium is about 1/4 as strong as steel by volume, so a 4x4 post with one inch walls would be an adequate replacement for your post with quarter inch walls (at that thickness it's probably cheaper to get a solid square bar).

but your post may be been overspecified to withstand some rusting. and so a lesser aluminium post may be usable. consult an engineer.